# QLocale::Language -- traditional and simplified chinese?

Tags: qt, locale

According to:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html

there is only one language for Chinese: `QLocale::Chinese` (value: 25). How to differentiate between **traditional** and **simplified** Chinese?

Answer (score 2):

It's not about country. It's about script:

```cpp
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Chinese, QLocale::SimplifiedChineseScript));
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Chinese, QLocale::TraditionalChineseScript));
```

Comment: There is QLocale::Taiwan now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an alternative method by locale name.
This:

```
QLocale chinese("zh"); // for Chinese
QLocale chinese("zh_Hans"); // for Simplified Chinese
QLocale chinese("zh_Hant"); // for Traditional Chinese
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Chinese, QLocale::China));  // Simplified Chinese
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Chinese, QLocale::Taiwan)); // Traditional Chinese
```

You can set the country with the second parameter.